# System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'ApplicationUser.LockoutEnd' is of type 'DateTimeOffset?'

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

For no reason when calling `userManager.FindByEmailAsync` it is throwing me the exception described.

```
...
([FromServices] UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, string email) {

await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
```

the aspnet core website is throwing:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.DateTimeOffset'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetFieldValueFromSqlBufferInternal[T](SqlBuffer data, _SqlMetaData metaData)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetFieldValueInternal[T](Int32 i)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 i)
```

I haven't added any DateTimeOffset fields to the AspnetUsers table.

Related Packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.10"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.10"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.10"/>
```

Comment: From my case I fixed it using `ALTER TABLE Users ALTER COLUMN LockoutEnd DATETIMEOFFSET`

Comment: @ImranQadirBaksh-Baloch in this case you have changed the data type on the database instead.

Comment: This was the default data type of `LockoutEnd` was DATETIMEOFFSET. Someone changes into DATETIME in DB. This is why issue started to happen

Answer (score 1):

the workaround I found to fix that was adding a mapping to the column, even this column being a native aspnet identity column. The column in question is the LockoutEnd column.

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            ...
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .Property(x => x.LockoutEnd)
                .HasConversion(
                    x => x.HasValue ? x.Value.DateTime : (DateTime?)null,
                    x => DateTimeOffset.Parse(x.ToString()));
        }
```